# Angular: How to throw an error inside an Observable

Tags: angular, observable

```
openModelSearchDialog() {
   const addRef = this.dialog.open(DiscoverModelEntryDialogComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      autoFocus: true,
      disableClose: true,
      data: []
   });
   addRef.afterClosed().subscribe(models => {
      if (models.length > 10) { 
          console.log("Oops, we got more than 10 models");
      }
       this.models = models;
       this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
   });
}
```

I tried the following:

```
addRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
   (models) => {
     this.models = models;
     this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
   },
   (error) => {
     if (this.models.length > 10) {
       console.log('Oops, we got more than ten models', error);
     }
   }
 )
```

I believe I have to use a `pipe()` but if so, I am not implementing it correctly:

```
addRef
   .afterClosed()
   .pipe(error => {
     if (this.models.length > 10) {
       return error;
     }
   })
   .subscribe(models => {
     this.models = models;
     this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
   });
```

Comment: So you want to throw the error if observable `addRef` emits an array that has a length less than 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple version of this will be after you subscribe
You can check res

```
if (this.countries.length>10) {
throw throwError(response);  
}
```

Import through error from rxjs
and you will be able to catch your error

```
,
(error) => {
   console.log(error) 
 }
```

}

Comment: You can also make use of iif operator of rxjs BTW I'm on mobile right now otherwise example would have shown

Comment: No pipe for the given code just check in the subscribe 
in your logic instead of return error on if use throwError operator if you're using rxjs 6

Comment: For rxjs 5 do this
throw Observable.throw('your message')

Answer (score 0):

A MatDialogRef afterClosed() does not throw errors. So, what you could do instead, is returning your ReturnObjects including error logic via the close() method.

```
// open dialog:
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample);
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: DialogData) => {
  if (result.customResult === DialogResponse.ERROR) {
    // do error handling here with 'result.customBody'
    console.error('error response from afterClosed is: ', result.customBody);
  } else {
    // do success handling here with 'result.customBody'
    console.log('succes response from afterClosed is: ', result.customBody);
  }
});
```

export interfaces and enums:

```
export interface DialogData {
    customResult: DialogResponse;
    customBody: any;
}

export enum DialogResponse {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    ERROR = 'error',
}
```

Dialog example:

```
// dialog-example.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-example',
    templateUrl: 'dialog-example.html',
})
export class DialogExample {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogExample>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData
    ) {}

    public closeWithSuccess() {
        this.dialogRef.close(
            {
                customResult: DialogResponse.SUCCESS,
                customBody: 'all happy ;-)'
            }
        );
    }

    public closeWithFail() {
        this.dialogRef.close(
            {
                customResult: DialogResponse.ERROR,
                customBody: 'more than 10 countries do not exist on this planet, lolz'
            });
    }
}
```

and dialog html:

```
// dialog-example.html:
<button (click)="closeWithSuccess()">close with success</button>
<button (click)="closeWithFail()">close with fail</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vsb3m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-example.html)

Comment: of course, you do not have to limit the data for SUCCESS/ERROR only, you can also bypass any data. Ive updated my answer for including an SUCCESS/ERROR type by an additional customBody of type any